# Static typing in html for angular in Visual Studio

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

Is there any way to check if html is valid and to have some intellisense? I mean I need something like typescript, but for html. For example I would like to get compilation errors when I use directives which are not exists. Or properties of scope what are not declared (in case of TS).

update:
I basically need kinda tsx for angular. And it's already addressed here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6508

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to use WebStorm which is a smart coding assistance for JavaScript and compiled-to-JavaScript languages, Node.js, HTML and CSS. 
One of the best for Angular. 
It has free 30-day trial and you can download it from the link below:
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: How exactly does it help with static typing in html templates for angular?